# how to improve searching index in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, performance, dataframe, search

Given a pandas dataframe with a timestamp index, sorted.
I have a label and I need to find the closest index to that label.
Also, I need to find a smaller timestamp, so the search should be computed in the minor timestamps.
Here is my code:

```
import pandas as pd
import datetime

data = [i for i in range(100)]
dates = pd.date_range(start="01-01-2018", freq="min", periods=100)
dataframe = pd.DataFrame(data, dates)

label = "01-01-2018 00:10:01"
method = "pad"
tol = datetime.timedelta(seconds=60)
idx = dataframe.index.get_loc(key=label, method="pad", tolerance=tol)

print("Closest idx:"+str(idx))
print("Closest date:"+str(dataframe.index[idx]))
```

the searching is too slow. Is there a way to improve it?

Answer (score 1):

This *probably* doesn't take into account that `dates` are sorted and thus performs as O(n). Try using binary-search on `dates`, that would perform as O(log(n)) (avoid implementing your own, look for a standard module, maybe it exists in numpy).